# Is my proof acceptable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Show that

$$\begin{aligned} \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} \bigg( \displaystyle\int_n^\infty |g(x)| dx +  \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-n } |g(x)| dx  \bigg) =0
\end{aligned}$$

*My attempt to Proof:

Since $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.  $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} |g(x)| dx < \infty$

*And we have,*

$$\begin{aligned} \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} \bigg( \displaystyle\int_n^\infty |g(x)| dx +  \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-n } |g(x)| dx  \bigg) \\
= \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} \bigg(  \lim\limits_{i\mapsto\infty} \displaystyle\int_n^i |g(x)| dx +  \lim\limits_{i\mapsto\infty} \displaystyle\int_{-i}^{- n} |g(x)| dx  \bigg)  \\
= \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty}  \lim\limits_{i\mapsto\infty}\bigg(   \displaystyle\int_n^i |g(x)| dx +   \displaystyle\int_{-i}^{- n} |g(x)| dx  \bigg) 
\end{aligned}$$

*notice that $i,n \mapsto \infty, therefore, i = n \forall \,\, i,n \in \mathbb{R}$*
*Hence, since the lower and upper integral are equal, then*
$$\begin{aligned}& \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} \bigg( \displaystyle\int_n^\infty |g(x)| dx +  \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-n } |g(x)| dx  \bigg) \\
 = & \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty}  \lim\limits_{i\mapsto\infty}\bigg(   \displaystyle\int_n^i |g(x)| dx +   \displaystyle\int_{-i}^{- n} |g(x)| dx  \bigg)\\
= & \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} (0 +0) \\
= & \ \ \  0
\end{aligned}$$
*Therefore*
$$\begin{aligned} \lim\limits_{n\mapsto\infty} \bigg( \displaystyle\int_n^\infty |g(x)| dx +  \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-n } |g(x)| dx  \bigg) =0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: "$i,n\to\infty$, therefore $i=n$"????????????????????????????????? (If this were valid it would show every integral equals $0$)

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're in an intro measure theory course (as you likely are if you're asking this), you might want to justify more why
$$\int_n^{\infty} |g(x)| \, dx = \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} \int_n^i |g(x)| \, dx.$$

Secondly, I have no idea how you go from the double limit to saying "the lower and upper integral are equal [what does this mean?] and hence..."

To me, it seems you do some arbitrary limit computation, and then just rewrite the statement of the theorem.